# Can I setup a 1:1 replacement for formula calculations in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose I have one Excel sheet or region like this:

```
Good        5
OK          4
Acceptable  3
Poor        2
Bad         1
Nothing     0
```

And now I have another region like this:

```
Task 1      Good
Task 2      OK
Task 3      Good
Task 4      Acceptable

Total       ...
```

The words are obviously text values. For the `Total` cell, I want to calculate the average of the tasks. I want the *strings* to be interpreted as the *numbers* in the first chart. In other words, Total should be the average of 5, 4, 5, and 3.

Basically, I want a 1:1 map of "if you see *this thing* in a cell, treat it as *this other thing* when you do math on that cell." If the value in the cell doesn't exist in the map, a `!#REF` or some kind of error value is acceptable. (I don't need a "treat unknown values as this default" is what I'm saying...although if that's possible that might be nice to know in the future, and if a default *must* be given that's fine too.)

I'd like to be able to easily add more values to the mapping at will, so I don't want to do a whole ton of if/else if/else if... stuff in each calculated cell. (Or imagine if there were 50 different possible words instead of just 5.)

Is this possible with Excel? (I'm on the latest Office 365 version if it matters.)

Comment: This site is not a free scripting site. If you have tried something and it did not work, share your code/scripts so we can help you debug it. But as it stands, this question will most likely be closed for lack of showing effort.

Comment: This is quite possible you could use a simple formula like this : `=AVERAGE(XLOOKUP(G2:G5,B2:B7,C2:C7))` --> Consider the range `G2:G5` as the second range in the another region while `B2:B7` & `C2:C7` as the actual range in the first region.

Comment: @giacomo1968 Do you have any keywords you can suggest for how I might search for this kind of functionality? Maybe the name of a function or something that can do it? I'm all for figuring things out and I don't need to be handed a solution, but I have no point of reference other than this arbitrary description of "if this value then treat as that value". So "try looking at the SOMETHING function" would be a sufficient answer for me. I could easily write code to do it in Python or any number of other languages, but I'm trying to do it with Excel.

Comment: @fdmillion you won't find anything as such by any keywords you need to think and apply the functions. I understand it is sometimes hard to use the exact keywords, but it totally depends on one who is very used to use any specific tools. Also you could try the one i have commented.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya `XLOOKUP` looks like it might be exactly what I need. If you want to post an answer suggesting using that function I'll mark it as solved!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I get your point, but Excel has 450+ functions and many can be applied and used in lots of ways. It's unlikely anyone who's not a full-time Excel dev knows everything Excel can do with all its functions. All I was looking for, which you provided (thanks), was a step in the right direction. (There seems to be this attitude that SE users are always looking for someone to do their work for them - that's not always the case, sometimes people, or at least I, just need a pointer in the right direction.) No hostility here btw, and thanks again for the help. :)

Comment: Not answering the Excel part of the question, but more generally you should be VERY wary of treating categorical data like this as if it is truly quantitative. By doing any kind of maths, such as an average, you are assuming that this scale is somehow scientific and the values have numerical meaning, which they almost certainly do not. Is "Good" exactly 25% better than "OK"? Is "Acceptable" precisely 3 times better than "Bad"? If not, then rethink your summary. Maybe report on the most common answer and how many times it occurs, or look at calculating something like a NetSat score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asked by OP and commented above the solution using `XLOOKUP()` function would work as it seems clearly.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G7`

```
=AVERAGE(XLOOKUP(G2:G5,B2:B7,C2:C7))
```

---

One another way, I like to use the `MMULT()`, just sharing although `XLOOKUP()` most promising, simple and sleek here.

[image]

---

```
=AVERAGE(MMULT(N(G2:G5=TOROW(B2:B7)),C2:C7))
```

---